# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"firsttry.c"'

Tags: bashrc

My code---

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
}
```

and I get bash: syntax error near unexpected token `"firsttry.c"'

Comment: Yeah, that's not bash.

Comment: you are trying to execute C from within a shell script?

Comment: What's the actual line you typed in to the shell?

Answer (score 2):

That's a C program, not a shell script. You have to compile it, which gets you an executable you can run.

On a modern Unix/Linux type system, the simplest way to do that is:

```
$ make firsttry
```

That only works if your local [`make(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/make) installation has rules built into it to make it understand that it can make the `firsttry` executable from `firsttry.c` without needing explicit rules in a [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile).

On systems without that bit of smarts built in, you can do it the old-fashioned way:

```
$ cc firsttry.c -o firsttry
```

Either way, *then* you can run it:

```
$ ./firsttry
hello, world
```

Comment: Or use [TCC](http://bellard.org/tcc/) to build and run in one go.